# Xamarin Border Radius AppCompat

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-appcompat

It seems that the BorderRadius attribute is not working when including AppCompat in the project.

I tried to create a custom render like this discussed [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/180130), but it didn't work:

```
namespace Xamarin.Forms
{
    public class CustomButton : Button  
    {
        public CustomButton():base()
        {   
        }

        protected override void OnParentSet()
        {
            base.OnParentSet();
        }
    }
}
```

In the Android project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomButton), typeof(CustomButtonRenderer))]
namespace CalculateurMadelin.Droid.Renderers
{
        public class CustomButtonRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.ButtonRenderer
    { }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can load an Android `drawable` in your custom renderer to define the background on your `AppCompat.Button`:

---

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomButton), typeof(CustomButtonRenderer))]
namespace AppCompatRender.Droid
{
    public class CustomButtonRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                Control.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.CustomButtonBackground);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add a new `Resources/Drawable` that matches the name you are using in your `SetBackgroundResource` (i.e.. `CustomButtonBackground.axml`), in this I am setting a corner radius of the rectangle as `10dp`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

[image]

Comment: So the BorderRadius property simple don't work on Android?

Answer (score 0):

That's true, custom renderers for Button (and also Picker, Switch, Frame etc.) are not called with AppCompat.

Link with the investigation:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/180130/#Comment_180130

Link describing a solution:
http://www.isosoft.org/taoffi/post/2016/03/26/Xamarin-forms-so-you-lost-your-rounded-buttons
(corrected link error)
The cleaner way is to inherit from a Button and setup a custom renderer for inherited control.